# remove chars in String javascript Regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a chain like this of get page

```
file.php?Valor1=one&Valor2=two&Valor3=three
```

I would like to be able to delete the get request parameter with only having the value of it. for example , `remove two`
**Result**

```
file.php?Valor1=one&Valor3=three
```

Try with

```
stringvalue.replace(new RegExp(value+"[(&||\s)]"),'');
```

Comment: Can you include the `RegExp` that you tried at Question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a regular expression that matches an ampersand (`&`), followed by a series of characters that are not equals signs (`[^=]+`), an equals sign (`=`), the literal value `two` and either the next ampersand or the end of line `(&|$)`:

```
/&[^=]+=two(&|$)/
```

```js
let input = 'file.php?&Valor1=one&Valor2=two&Valor3=three';
let output = input.replace(/&[^=]+=two/, '');

console.log(output);
```

If you're getting the value to be removed from a variable:

```js
let two = 'two';
let re = RegExp('&[^=]+=' + two + '(&|$)');

let input = 'file.php?&Valor1=one&Valor2=two&Valor3=three';
let output = input.replace(re, '');

console.log(output);
```

In this case, you need to make sure that your variable value does not contain any characters that have special meaning in regular expressions. If that's the case, you need to properly escape them.

**Update**
To address the input string in the updated question (no ampersand before first parameter):

```js
let one = 'one';
let re = RegExp('([?&])[^=]+=' + one + '(&?|$)');

let input = 'file.php?Valor1=one&Valor2=two&Valor3=three';
let output = input.replace(re, '$1');

console.log(output);
```

Comment: If the value two , comes from a variable, how would the concatenation be?

Comment: Don't know what you mean.

Comment: Sorry, error when writing the question was an & more, if I want to delete the value one, do not perform the replace. Can be by that character of more

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RegExp` constructor, `RegExp`, template literal  `&[a-zA-Z]+\\d+=(?=${remove})${remove})` to match `"&"` followed by "a-z", "A-Z", followed by one or more digits followed by `""`, followed by matching value to pass to `.replace()`

```js
var str = "file.php?&Valor1=one&Valor2=two&Valor3=three";

var re = function(not) {
           return new RegExp(`&[a-zA-Z]+\\d+=(?=${not})${not}`)
         }

var remove = "two";

var res = str.replace(re(remove), "");

console.log(res);

var remove = "one";

var res = str.replace(re(remove), "");

console.log(res);

var remove = "three";

var res = str.replace(re(remove), "");

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a much cleaner solution would be to use the [URLSearchParams api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

```
var paramsString = "Valor1=one&Valor2=two&Valor3=three"
var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(paramsString);

//Iterate the search parameters.
//Each element will be [key, value]
for (let p of searchParams) {
    if (p[1] == "two") {
        searchParams.delete(p[0]);
    }
}

console.log(searchParams.toString()); //Valor1=one&Valor3=three
```